# scipy fft returns null imaginary part

Tags: python, scipy, fft

First of all, I apologize for being an absolute beginner in both python and signal processing.

I am trying to simulate an impulse signal (or a delta function) propagating along spatial x-axis over time. Then, I would like to perform Fourier Transformation on amplitude vs x-axis for each time and then amplitude vs t-axis for each point in space. The problem I'm facing is that the Fourier coefficients are all real valued. If I "implot" the imaginary part over spatial and temporal axis, you can see, all of these are shown to be zero. However, my understanding was that, the impulse signal at t = 0, x = 0, should have null imaginary coefficient. But after that, for all the other t and/or x's, there should be a real valued imaginary coefficient.

Please refer to this site http://madebyevan.com/dft/ where one can interactively make waveforms and observe the Fourier Transformation. In the f(x) box, please put "spike(x-0)", "spike(x-1)" etc. to simulate my problem and expected result.

I have tried the following code using scipy.fftpack. There are some extra lines to analyze the impulse signal travelling in x axis and x-t plane.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import math
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy import ndimage

L = 10
k = np.pi/L
w = np.pi*2
n = 5

# Number of samplepoints
Nx = 1000
Nt = 500
# sample spacing
l = 1.0/Nx
T = 1.0/Nt

x = np.linspace(0, Nx*l*L, Nx)
t = np.linspace(0, Nt*T*L, Nt)

x = np.round(x,2)
t = np.round(t,2)

# function to produce impulse 
def gw(xx, tt):
    if xx == tt:
        kk = 1
    else:
        kk = 0    
    return (kk)

fig = plt.figure()
yg = np.array([gw(i, j) for j in t for i in x])
YG = yg.reshape(Nt, Nx)

# how impulse propagate in x-t plane
plt.imshow(YG, interpolation='bilinear',aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar();

# how impulse propagate in x-axis for t = 2 and t = 100
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, YG[2,:], x, YG[100,:])
plt.show()

# FFT in x-axis at each point in time
yxf = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))
for i in range(Nt):
    yx = YG[i,:]
    yxf[i,:] = scipy.fftpack.fft(yx)

plt.imshow(np.imag(yxf[:,:Nx]), interpolation='bilinear',aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar();
plt.show()

# FFT in t-axis at each point in space
ytf = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))
for i in range(Nx):
    yt = YG[:,i]
    ytf[:,i] = scipy.fftpack.fft(yt)

plt.imshow(np.imag(ytf[:Nt,:]), interpolation='bilinear',aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar();
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have `yxf = np.zeros((Nt, Nx))`; this creates an array of 64 bit floating point *real* values.  Then you have `yxf[i,:] = scipy.fftpack.fft(yx)`. Assigning in-place to a numpy array does not change its type, so the imaginary parts are discarded.  Did you not get a warning about this?  I expect to see the warning `ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part`.

Comment: FYI: The function `scipy.fftpack.fft` accepts an `axis` argument.  You can replace the loop that you use to compute `yxf` with the single line `yxf = scipy.fftpack.fft(YG, axis=1)`.  Similarly, you can compute `ytf` with `ytf = scipy.fftpack.fft(YG, axis=0)`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. And thanks a lot for the tip on for-loop too!